# Is there any way to check whether a list is in np.array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find a way to check if my image has any specific RGB value.

I have a list

`rgb = [128,134,45]`

and an image

`img = array([[[0,0,0],[128,134,45],[128,134,45],...,[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]])`
shape =(64,64,3)

and want to get positions (i,j) where rgb matches img[j][i] such as `pos = [(0,1),(0,2),...]`

I tried to use "in" like `if rgb in img: brbr` but didn't work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. rbg in img works for me

Comment: Easiest way is just loop through the items in the image but this is not very efficient

Comment: Please provide a better example output. Like what do you want when multiple items match in one element?

Comment: @SeanSdahl that is definitely not the easiest way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @Bendik's answer, but this extra step gives you an array of all the locations that match:

```
np.rot90(np.array(np.where((img==rgb).all(axis=2))))
```

For example:

```
img = np.zeros((64,64,3))
rgb = [128,134,45]
img[1,2] = rgb
img[23,32] = rgb
# These are the values we want to find - (1,2) and (23,32)
result = np.rot90(np.array(np.where((img==rgb).all(axis=2))))
print(result)

#OUTPUT:
array([[23, 32],
       [ 1,  2]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>>np.where((img==rgb).all(axis=2))
(array([0, 0], dtype=int32), array([1, 2], dtype=int32))
```

this gives you the indexies of your rgb values

`img[0][1]`
and
`img[0][2]`